xparse, arguments delimiters and unexpected behavior
I start with a simplified macro of what I was doing:
\NewDocumentCommand{\lr}{r{(}{)}}{\left(#1\right)}
with this $$\lr(\int x^2\,dx)$$ LaTeX returns 
but i dont know why when i use $$\lr(\int (x^2+x)\,dx)$$ i get 
and no something like this 
I’m glad it’s not like that, haha, but wouldn’t this be the expected behavior?

Yes, it's the expected behavior: \NewDocumentCommand and \NewDocumentEnvironment try hard to get nesting of delimited arguments correct.
The behavior was set up mainly for optional arguments containing [...], say a \cite[p.~3]{abc} inside an optional argument. This often happens with theorems and their attribution argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theoreminner}{Theorem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\theoreminner}{\theoreminner[{#1}]}%
}{\endtheoreminner}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lr}{r{(}{)}}{\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
No optional argument here.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[See \cite[p.~3]{abc}]
This has the optional argument.
\end{theorem}

\begin{gather*}
\lr(\int x^2\,dx) \\
\lr(\int(x^2+x)\,dx)
\end{gather*}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{abc} Something
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}



Perfect! Grazie mille!
